# Unable to establish SSL connection when using wget to download GEDI data from LP DAAC data pool

Tags: ssl, wget

I was using wget to download GEDI data from LP DAAC data pool. It always returns an error of "unable to establish SSL connection". I attempted wget in promote or Pycharm and added the "--no-check-certificate" configuration.

The wget is the newest release (1.21.3,64bit).
OS: windows11.

from the following massages, I guess the connection to EarthData is successful because it returns the data downloading link that I can open manually in the browser and then can start downloading. This error could happen in the last step that wget starts accessing the returned link and then downloading.

returned messages:
--2022-08-14 09:51:09--  https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov//GEDI_L1_L2/GEDI/GEDI01_B.002/2019.04.20/GEDI01_B_2019110092939_O01996_01_T03334_02_005_01_V002.h5
Resolving e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov (e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov)... 2001:49c8:4000:127d::133:130, 152.61.133.130
Connecting to e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov (e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov)|2001:49c8:4000:127d::133:130|:443... failed: Bad file descriptor.
Connecting to e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov (e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov)|152.61.133.130|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov/oauth/authorize?scope=uid&app_type=401&client_id=ijpRZvb9qeKCK5ctsn75Tg&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fe4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov%2Foauth&state=aHR0cHM6Ly9lNGZ0bDAxLmNyLnVzZ3MuZ292Ly9HRURJX0wxX0wyL0dFREkvR0VESTAxX0IuMDAyLzIwMTkuMDQuMjAvR0VESTAxX0JfMjAxOTExMDA5MjkzOV9PMDE5OTZfMDFfVDAzMzM0XzAyXzAwNV8wMV9WMDAyLmg1 [following]
--2022-08-14 09:51:55--  https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov/oauth/authorize?scope=uid&app_type=401&client_id=ijpRZvb9qeKCK5ctsn75Tg&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fe4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov%2Foauth&state=aHR0cHM6Ly9lNGZ0bDAxLmNyLnVzZ3MuZ292Ly9HRURJX0wxX0wyL0dFREkvR0VESTAxX0IuMDAyLzIwMTkuMDQuMjAvR0VESTAxX0JfMjAxOTExMDA5MjkzOV9PMDE5OTZfMDFfVDAzMzM0XzAyXzAwNV8wMV9WMDAyLmg1
Resolving urs.earthdata.nasa.gov (urs.earthdata.nasa.gov)... 2001:4d0:241a:4081::89, 198.118.243.33
Connecting to urs.earthdata.nasa.gov (urs.earthdata.nasa.gov)|2001:4d0:241a:4081::89|:443... failed: Bad file descriptor.
Connecting to urs.earthdata.nasa.gov (urs.earthdata.nasa.gov)|198.118.243.33|:443... connected.
Unable to establish SSL connection.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem still. Did you manage to find a solution/workaround?